# How can i migrate Video For Windows code to something better?

Tags: c#, c++, directshow, directshow.net, vfw

I have an IP camera streaming video into blackbox buffer code that a company provided me. They also provided me example code of how i can take the buffer and convert it to an unsigned char* array. With this array I can create an AVI file and save the video buffer to it and create a video file.

```
for( unsigned short lLine = 0; lLine < mSizeY -1; lLine++)
{
    NumOfLines = lLine;
    unsigned char *lCurLine = (unsigned char *)aBuffer + (lLine) * mSizeX * mBPP;
    unsigned char *lCurLineInv = temp + (mSizeY - lLine - 1) * mSizeX * mBPP;
    ::memcpy(lCurLineInv, lCurLine, mSizeX * mBPP );
}
AVIStreamWrite(mAVICompressedStream, mLastSample, 1, temp, mImageSize, AVIIF_KEYFRAME, &lSamplesWritten, &lBytesWritten )
```

Its a terrible system in so many ways. Including the fact that it's all done in VFW

Currently im doing all of this code in C# and in a C++/CLi DLL. I know how to use Directshow.Net and i was wondering if there is a more elegant way to save this video buffer i have to an avi file or something that i can easily work on in say DirectShow or DirectShow.net?

Comment: Maybe i can create a DirectShow.net filter to handle it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DirectShow.net's source filter sample in `Samples\Misc\GSSF`. I probably wouldn't rewrite to DS just to avoid VFW, though: I've had stability issues using it even in C++, so only I'd do it to get output format flexability. Media Foundation is the new hotness if you can ditch < Vista.

Comment: i want to ditch VFW because it saves in uncompressed AVI and only to a file size of 2gb. which equates to <30 seconds of video. the compressors with VFW suck. so was hoping for directshow where i could connect to a graph and convert and compress all at once

Comment: I'm not super knowledgeable about VFW, but you might need to tweak the params to `AVIMakeCompressedStream`: using `AVICOMPRESSF_KEYFRAMES` and a good FOURCC should give you far smaller files than 2GB! If none of the preinstalled codecs are good enough, you could try bundling http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/

Comment: i tried the x264 and it doesnt seem to change the size of the video even after playing around with it

Comment: Also want to ditch VFW because im using a C# application and calling VFW through a C++/CLI dll which ramps my resources up to 510,000k of RAM

Answer (score 0):

Check out AForge.Net. Its a c# wrapper for VfW, DirectShow and FFMpeg. The FFMpeg route should be the most elegant and robust.